# How to sync just android 2.2 froyo code?

Tags: android, android-source

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b froyo
error: revision froyo in manifests not found
```

Latest version 2.3 required 64 bit machine to build,How to get just froyo code?

Comment: AFAIK, 2.2 also requires 64-bit Ubuntu machines, otherwise it will throw lost of exceptions. I encountered the same when I was working with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation of what is happening to the froyo branch and how to workaround the problem:

https://groups.google.com/group/android-building/browse_thread/thread/d6c505873a8680a7

If you want to look for the appropriate tag to check out exact code branch, try this:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+refs

So looking at the list, the branch that you should try would be: `android-2.2.2_r1`

Comment: Look out: second link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/repo -b froyo`

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me.

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-2.2_r1.1
```

I guess r1.1 is the release branch. can someone affirm this?