# Where to download Android 2.2 Froyo source code?

Tags: android-source, android-2.2-froyo

I want to download android 2.2 froyo source code, but actually here https://android.googlesource.com is available android 2.3 gingerbread. How can I switch to previous version?

Comment: similar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849700/how-to-sync-just-android-2-2-froyo-code

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to pick a project and select the 'froyo' branch or use one of the 'android-2.2' tags to pull the 2.2 source after cloning the project's repo.