# Android kernel source code

Tags: android, android-source

I downloaded Android 2.2 source code a long time ago but it didn't have the kernel source code. I looked online and it seems like there is a separate Android kernel source I should download.

Someone gave me this address

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common
```

but I think I should specify the version and branch. 
So what is the full command to download Android 2.2 froyo kernel source code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sync just android 2.2 froyo code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849700/how-to-sync-just-android-2-2-froyo-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get tools:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg sun-java5-jdk flex bison gperf libsdl-dev libesd0-dev libwxgtk2.6-dev build-essential zip curl libncurses5-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Get repo tool:

```
$ curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > ~/bin/repo
$ chmod a+x ~/bin/repo
```

Get source code:

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

OR

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b release-1.0
```

OR

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-sdk-1.5_r2  
$ repo sync`
```

Sync single project:

```
$ repo sync {project_name}
```

Get common kernel:

```
$ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common
```

Answer (score 2):

For other kernels you could use any of these:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common.git

git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/goldfish.git

git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm.git

git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/omap.git

git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/samsung.git

git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/tegra.git
```

Answer (score 2):

`git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common.git` is not enough !

```
cd common
```

List all the branches:

```
git branch -a
```

Checkout one of them:

```
git checkout android-2.6.39
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Aloongs answer ->

Get the source using Git:

```
git checkout -b android-2.6.35 origin/android-2.6.35
```

where `-b` = branch name and start point is android-2.6.35

To list the remote branches use the following command:

```
git branch -r
```